# Add a key binding with vim under VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

With Visual Studio Code, I like to use vim. A bit as the `print()` function, we can insert `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` to debug a code.  How to create a key binding with vim under VS code so that I can insert `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`?

In my `.vimrc` config, I used

```
"Insert the line 'import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace'
noreabbrev __i  import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

but now in VS Code, it doesn't work. What is the equivalent in VS Code for the file `.vimrc`

Comment: This will not strictly answer your question but: (1) vscode has a very nice debugger which would may want to consider for... well, debugging... (2) if you want to insert predefined bits of code, you should look into snippets, which are designed for this purpose and would avoid using another keyboard shortcut https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: @François I modified my question. Can you make a full answer in details to see what you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into user snippets, which are designed to insert predefined bits of code. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets

In your case, the snippet could be defined by:

```
{
    "Python ipdb": {
        "prefix": "ipdb",
        "body": [
            "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()",
        ],
        "description": "Add ipdb breakpoint"
    }
}
```

But again, vscode has a very nice embedded [debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Comment: I agree with you that VS code has a nice debugger, but ipdb allows me interact with the code a bit more deeply than what VS code do.